# Script errors after moving wordpress to a new domain

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've moved my wordpress from a domain to another. On the first domain everything worked fine. On the second i get a bunch of JS errors logged to the console. The url of the website is https://dexport.co.uk

The errors I have been getting look like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
jquery.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:752 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:752
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js?ver=6.7.6:13
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at layerslider.transitions.js?ver=6.7.6:13
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8:23
    at jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8:23
jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.4.8:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.4.8:7
gtm4wp-form-move-tracker.js?ver=1.8.1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at gtm4wp-form-move-tracker.js?ver=1.8.1:1
add-to-cart.js?ver=3.4.5:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at add-to-cart.js?ver=3.4.5:2
woocommerce-add-to-cart.js?ver=5.5.4:1 Uncaught TypeError: window.jQuery is not a function
    at woocommerce-add-to-cart.js?ver=5.5.4:1
(index):1315 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):1315
(index):1415 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):1415
(index):1449 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):1449
core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I added a few lines to my wp-config:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

But no succes

Comment: There is also `unexpected token` `�:��U�:��U�5�U�r�U�:��U�:��U@�:��Ub]` in your main jquery and greensock. Fix that first. May be replace it with new file.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages say: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

I suppose you are storing those libraries in your server and you are not using CDN.
Verify that the path that leads to libraries such as jQuery, is properly defined in your installation and that file permissions are properly set.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open your Active theme’s header.php file

2) Paste below script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

just after the head tag.

3) Save your file.

Comment: This did something as you can see on the updated version. But there's still some errors left.

Comment: Using a higher version of Jquery helped. 3.1 It's showing even more now. Still some errors